# pick first and last int value from and list and continue the sequence till the end of list

Tags: python

Input:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15]
```

Expected output:

```
l2 = [[1,3],[5],[7],[9,12],[15]]
```

In `l2`, the first nested list is the sequence from 1 to 3, so the first and last values are picked. 5 doesn't have any adjacent values (+/- 1), so 5 is in the second sublist, this follows until the sequence is exhausted.

Below is the code I have tried:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15]
l=[]
l2 = []

def nested_list(n):
    for i in n:
        if i not in l:
            l.append(i)
            if i+1 not in a:
                break

l2.append(l)      
nested_list(a)
print(l2)
```

It's not iterating through all the elements of `l1`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l=[]
cnt=0
a+=[-1] #added dummy value

for i in range(1,len(a)):

  if a[i] == a[i-1]+1:
    cnt+=1
  else:
    if cnt > 0  :
      l.append([a[i-1]-cnt,a[i-1]])   
    else:
      l.append([a[i-1]])  
    cnt=0

a=a[:-1] #remove the dummy value
```

Dummy value is added so that the iteration will loop through all the element of the original list

Comment: Nice solution and I was about to post the same solution XD. Instead of adding `[999999]` consider adding `[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library, [intspan](https://intspan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), to get results like what you want.

```
from intspan import intspan

l1 = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15]
M = []

for tpl in intspan(l1).ranges():
    M.append(tpl)

print(M)
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 3), (5, 5), (7, 7), (9, 12), (15, 15)]
```

To get the same data structure as posted originally:

```
for a,b in intspan(l1).ranges():
    if a != b:
        M.append([a,b])
    else:
        M.append([a])


[[1, 3], [5], [7], [9, 12], [15]]
```

Comment: very clever solution, but it does print twice the element when it should just do it once according to the question. Perhaps do `M.append(list(set(tpl)))` to prevent this?

Comment: @Eric Using a set will not maintain order of the pair. The start and end numbers might get reversed.

Comment: Good point. Of course you could sort them afterwards but that is more complex than your current solution with conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not perfect but it works.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15]
l2 = []

start_ind = None

for x in range(len(l1)-1):
    """
    Lets asign a start index from where to make the slice
    """
    if start_ind == None:
        start_ind = x

    """
    Check the two nearest numbers
    """
    if abs(l1[x] - l1[x+1]) != 1:
        """
        If the start index is the same as the end index:
            add first and last values
        Else:
            Only add the first value
        """
        if start_ind != x:
            l2.append([l1[start_ind], l1[x]])
        else:
            l2.append([l1[start_ind]])

        start_ind = None

"""
This is for the last value if it hasn't been added
"""
if l1[-1] != l2[-1][-1]:
    l2.append([l1[-1]])

print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

And another solution :-)

```
l1 = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11,12,15]
l2 = []
sequence = []
for i in range(1, len(l1)+1):
    sequence.append(l1[i-1])
    if i >= len(l1):
        l2.append(sequence)
        break
    if l1[i-1] != l1[i] - 1:
        l2.append(sequence)
        sequence = []

print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the [`Gaps and Islands problem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands).

```py
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 43, 44, 10, 11, 12, 1, 1, 7, 9, 42, 170, 170, 170]
l1.sort()
prev_elem = l1[0]
dense_rank = 1
curr_group = prev_elem - dense_rank
islands = [[prev_elem]]
for elem in l1[1:]:
    if elem != prev_elem:
        dense_rank += 1
    group = elem - dense_rank
    if group != curr_group:
        if islands[-1][0] != prev_elem:
            islands[-1].append(prev_elem)
        islands.append([elem])
        curr_group = group
    prev_elem = elem
print(islands)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3], [5], [7], [9, 12], [42, 44], [170]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the support, below is the code i tried, the answer was correct.

```
a = [1,3,4,5,7,9,11,13]
l = []
l2 = []

for i in a:
    l.append(i)
    if i+1 not in a:
        if len(l)<2:
            l2.append([l[0]])
        else:
            l2.append([l[0], l[-1]])
        l.clear()
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

year = [[2002,2004,2005],[2003],[2004,2006,2008]]
M=[]
for i in year:
    for tpl in intspan(i).ranges():
        M.append(tpl)

Results:
[(2002, 2002),
 (2004, 2005),
 (2003, 2003),
 (2004, 2004),
 (2006, 2006),
 (2008, 2008)]

Iam not getting the right result. Iam trying to get the year span.