# Numpy detect incrementing ranges in list

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have a list that looks like this (its actually waaaaaaaay larger)

`1,2,3,4,6,7,9,12,14,15,16`

And I would like to autodetect ranges without gaps within it so I could get an array of tuples like this

`(1,4),(6,7),(9,9),(12,12),(14,16)`

Whats an efficient way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Not in numpy, but here is a way using [intspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130275/pick-first-and-last-int-value-from-and-list-and-continue-the-sequence-till-the-e/60130620#60130620)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We will use resort to slicing on a loop, but do all of the compute in the pre-processing part with NumPy to gain performance. Slicing on an array is  simply working on a view, hence should be pretty efficient. Here's one way to fulfill those -

```
def start_stop_with_seq(a):
    m = np.r_[True,np.diff(a)!=1,True]
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m)
    return [(a[i],a[j-1]) for (i,j) in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [115]: a
Out[115]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16]

In [116]: start_stop_with_seq(a)
Out[116]: [(1, 4), (6, 7), (9, 9), (12, 12), (14, 16)]
```

**Approach #2**

We can index into an array equivalent of the input list for a vectorized solution with indexing that replaces the slicing part from the previous one -

```
def start_stop_with_seq_v2(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    m = np.r_[True,np.diff(a)!=1,True]
    return np.c_[a[m[:-1]], a[m[1:]]]
```

Output for given sample -

```
In [163]: start_stop_with_seq_v2(a)
Out[163]: 
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 9,  9],
       [12, 12],
       [14, 16]])
```

This approach makes sense if there are many intervals for the output.

#### Benchmarking

Testing on a *waaaaaaaay larger* (similar to given sample) dataset -

```
In [217]: np.random.seed(0)

In [218]: a = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,100000,(200000))).tolist()

In [219]: %timeit intspan(a).ranges()
29.9 ms ± 343 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [220]: %timeit start_stop_with_seq(a)
14.3 ms ± 84.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [221]: %timeit start_stop_with_seq_v2(a)
6.78 ms ± 57.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: is there an advange for this over intspan?

Comment: @user2741831 Not sure. Haven't worked with intspan. Benchmark and let me know?

Comment: ill see if I get to it. But if it works well enough I'll probably just stick with it

Comment: @user2741831 On popular demand, added benchmarking. Satisfies your needs?

Comment: @user2741831 If your question has been answered or helpful, you can accept and upvote. More info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: sry forgot about that